# Inline entity form ajax

Tags: 8, forms, entities, ajax

I am trying to update some field options in an inline entity form with ajax. This should happen, when someone selects a value in an other field.

I already have some code which "works", but the problem is that you can edit multiple items and there seems to be a problem with the wrapper_id, because it is for all items the same and the *entityForm* function is called multiple times.

So what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

What about adding wrappers to the fields?

In your hook_form_alter:

```
$form['field_name']['#prefix'] = '<div class="last">';
$form['field_name']['#suffix'] = '</div><div class="clearfix"></div>';
```

Check https://www.webomelette.com/drupal-form-api-prefix-suffix

Comment: The problem is that you can edit multiple items at the same time and so every item has exactly the same wrapper. In the ajax callback you than can't detect the right one.

Comment: If you add  prefix and suffix with id, they won't have the same wrapper.

Comment: When I would add this code, all the items will have the same prefix and suffix, but for replacing to work, jQuery needs an unique selector.

Comment: Yes, this was an example. The prefix should also have an id which will be unique for each field. You have the field name, so you could add : $form['field_name']['#prefix'] = '<div class="last" id="' . field_name . '-wrapper">'; for example